# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal"

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to include Firebase analtyics and Google admob ads, but I get a few errors

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal"

This is my gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'maven'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.demoapp.demowork"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile "com.android.support:exifinterface:26.0.2"
    compile 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.2'
    compile'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.2'

    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'



    compile  'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.5.1'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.7'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'


    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.5'


    compile 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.7'

}

configurations.all {

    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '26.0.2'
            }
        }

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

this is the app class

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'
        }

        jcenter()


    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.26.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {

        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
       // google()

        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }



    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = '25.0.0'  // variable that can be referenced to keep support libs consistent
    commonLibVersion= '1.1.9'
    versionBuildTool = '24.0.3'
    versionCompiler = 25
    versionTarget = 23
    versionNameString = '1.0.0'
    javaSourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    javaTargetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

I have referred to a lot of stackoverflow questions and used the mutidex option also.

This is application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

}
```

I have used the latest libraries Referred here

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rel-notes

but I still get this error

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

```
                                                                               java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/internal/FirebaseInstanceIdInternal;
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar.getComponents(Unknown Source)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:52)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:539)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:355)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1739)
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1708)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5262)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4836)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4776)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:176)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.demoapp.demowork-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
                                                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar.getComponents(Unknown Source) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:52) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:539) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:355) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:324) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:310) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:53) 
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1739) 
                                                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1708) 
                                                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:47) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5262) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4836) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4776) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:176) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1498) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956) 
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751) 
                                                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.firebase.iid.internal.FirebaseInstanceIdInternal
                                                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                                                        ... 23 more
                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Any solution would be helpful

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade to this `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'`? Does it work?

Comment: I am using android sudio 2.3.3 , gradle:3.2.1 would require android studio 3.0

Comment: I'll recommend you to do the necessary updates.

Comment: update will take time I tried compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'){        force = true;}  compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4') {      force = true;    }
    compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.4')  {             force = true;         }but still I get the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/internal/FirebaseInstanceIdInternal;
 at com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar.getComponents(Unknown Source)
at com.google.firebase.components.zzf.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.2:52)